# Creating dynamic controls for project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create dymanic controls in my ASP.NET MVC Project.
For example

My Model contains an `IList<Product> Products`. Every product in this list contains a new `IList<ProductItem>`. 
Product item has properties Text and Value.

Now i want to create one DropDownList for every Products and every `dropdownlist` should contains items for ProductItem.

Is this possible with `HtmlHelpers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. 
In your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Product> model = GetProductList();
    View(model);
}
```

In your View:

```
@model IList<Products>
```

... and then later on ...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.Name, new SelectList(Model, "Name", "Value"))
```

Comment: Thanks! If i wrap it into an forech loop this will work i think.

Comment: Actually you don't have to wrap that in a for loop. In case you ARE in a for (or foreach) you can use just use @Html.DropDownList(...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use helpers, you can always do something like this:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <option value="@x.Value">@x.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```